# Retrieving Electronically Signed PDF from MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdf, signature

Do electronically signed PDFs need to be stored in a certain way in MySQL? I noticed that after storing a PDF with a valid electronic signature (verified in Acrobat Pro) and then retrieving it from my database, the signature is no longer valid. I can make local copies/email it/etc, and the signature is valid, but not after retrieval from MySQL. Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: How *do* you store PDF files in MySQL? Obviously they have to be stored in a way which does not change them.

Comment: Best solution is to store the pdf file in a folder and its name in database table. That is true for almost all kinds of files.

Answer (score 0):

PDF files can contain binary data which will be corrupted if you use a character (VARCHAR) data type to store it.  You must ensure that you store it in a binary data type that does not undergo any encoding/decoding on the way in or out. Probably MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB. You must also ensure that any code you write treats the PDF as a binary stream and does not do any encoding/decoding.